# How to sort positive and negative values in pandas dataframe by multiple criteria in the same group?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas-groupby, negative-number

How to **sort the 'Separate CY' column** by following the criteria below?

**Criteria:**

1. 'Group', 'Index', 'Ref' need to sort from A to Z in 'Group', then 'Index', after that 'Ref'. For (NFS, F1A, b); (NFS, F1A, a); (NFS-3M, F2L, b); (NFS, F1A, c); (NFS-3M, F2L, a), they will be sorted like this --> (NFS, F1A, a); (NFS, F1A, b); (NFS, F1A, c); (NFS-3M, F2L, a); (NFS-3M, F2L, b).
2. Each 'Group' in the same 'Index' in the same 'Ref' **has the same 'Normal balance side'**.
3. If 'Normal balance side' column is 'D' (values is generally **> 0**), sort from **max to min**.
4. If 'Normal balance side' column is 'C' (values is generally **< 0**), sort from **min to max**.
5. Values in the **opposite sign** of the 'Normal balance side' (if any) will be before 'Other' or 'Others' (if any). If more than 1 value, sort as **absolute values** from max to min.
6. If there are **0 values**, they will be between normal sign values and opposite sign values and sort 'Separate PY' column instead by following the criteria above. (No 0 values in both 'Separate CY' and 'Separate PY' in the same time.)
7. If there are the **same values**, sort 'Separate PY' column instead based on the criteria above.
8. If there are the same values in both 'Separate CY' and 'Separate PY', sort by order from top to bottom.
9. **'Other' or 'Others'** in 'Caption' column will be in the **last order**. (there are not more than 1 'Other' and 1 'Others' in the same 'Group' in the same 'Index' in the same 'Ref'.)
10. If there are **'Other' and 'Others'** in the same 'Group' in the same 'Index' in the same 'Ref', sort **'Other' before 'Others'**.

**Original dataframe:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Ref":["NFS", "NFS", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS", "NFS", "NFS", "NFS", "NFS", "NFS", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M", "NFS-3M"], "Index":["F1A", "F1A", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F3I_PO1.I1A", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F1A", "F1A", "F2L", "F2L", "F2L", "F1A", "F3I_PO1.I1", "F1A", "F1A", "F2L"], "Group":["b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "d", "b", "b", "b"], "Caption":["xxx", "dfasd", "bbbbb", "wewer", "qewqe", "uytuy", "sdf", "tu56r", "Other", "wer42", "eryru", "wetweryt", "eqwwqeqwq", "f", "asdfsad", "f", "asdfsad", "Others", "fa", "a", "sdf", "asdfsad", "qwewe"], "Normal balance side":["D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "C", "C", "C", "D", "C", "C", "C", "C"], "Separate CY":["-99", "53", "-87", "20", "0", "0", "47", "0", "33", "90", "-30", "33", "20", "2", "27", "38", "-1", "-100", "5", "69", "3", "-58", "20"], "Separate PY":["10", "84", "-9", "20", "20", "20", "6", "20", "1", "0", "-9", "1", "20", "70", "96", "4", "-54", "-50", "1", "55", "93", "-75", "10"]})
```

| Ref | Index | Group | Caption | Normal balance side | Separate CY | Separate PY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NFS | F1A | b | xxx | D | -99 | 10 |
| NFS | F1A | a | dfasd | D | 53 | 84 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | bbbbb | C | -87 | -9 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wewer | C | 20 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | qewqe | C | 0 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | uytuy | C | 0 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F3I_PO1.I1A | a | sdf | D | 47 | 6 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | Others | C | 55 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | Other | C | 33 | 1 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wer42 | C | 90 | 0 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | eryru | C | -30 | -9 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wetweryt | C | 33 | 1 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | eqwwqeqwq | C | 20 | 20 |
| NFS | F1A | b | f | D | 2 | 70 |
| NFS | F1A | b | asdfsad | D | 27 | 96 |
| NFS | F2L | a | f | C | 38 | 4 |
| NFS | F2L | a | asdfsad | C | -1 | -54 |
| NFS | F2L | a | Others | C | -100 | -50 |
| NFS | F1A | a | fa | D | 5 | 1 |
| NFS-3M | F3I_PO1.I1 | d | a | C | 69 | 55 |
| NFS-3M | F1A | b | sdf | C | 3 | 93 |
| NFS-3M | F1A | b | asdfsad | C | -58 | -75 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | qwewe | C | 20 | 10 |

**Expected result:**

| Ref | Index | Group | Caption | Normal balance side | Separate CY | Separate PY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NFS | F1A | b | asdfsad | D | 27 | 96 |
| NFS | F1A | b | f | D | 2 | 70 |
| NFS | F1A | b | xxx | D | -99 | 10 |
| NFS | F1A | a | dfasd | D | 53 | 84 |
| NFS | F1A | a | fa | D | 5 | 1 |
| NFS | F2L | a | asdfsad | C | -1 | -54 |
| NFS | F2L | a | f | C | 38 | 4 |
| NFS | F2L | a | Others | C | -100 | -50 |
| NFS-3M | F1A | b | asdfsad | C | -58 | -75 |
| NFS-3M | F1A | b | sdf | C | 3 | 93 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | bbbbb | C | -87 | -9 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | eryru | C | -30 | -9 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wer42 | C | 90 | 0 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wetweryt | C | 33 | 1 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | wewer | C | 20 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | eqwwqeqwq | C | 20 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | qwewe | C | 20 | 10 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | qewqe | C | 0 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | uytuy | C | 0 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | Other | C | 33 | 1 |
| NFS-3M | F2L | b | Others | C | 55 | 20 |
| NFS-3M | F3I_PO1.I1A | a | sdf | D | 47 | 6 |
| NFS-3M | F3I_PO1.I1 | d | a | C | 69 | 55 |

Comment: Can you clarify what *"'Group', 'Index', 'Ref' do not need to sort, the order is from top to bottom but the same value needs to be consecutive."* means?

Comment: I change the paragraph to be "'Group', 'Index', 'Ref' need to sort the same value continuously from top to bottom.", e.g. NFS, NFS, NFS-3M, NFS-3M, NFS --> NFS, NFS, NFS, NFS-3M, NFS-3M

Comment: But this might not be possible; imagine four rows with (NFS, F1A), (NFS, F2L), (NFS-3M, F1A), (NFS-3M, F2L). How would you sort them?

Comment: I've changed the first criteria to be sorted from A to Z from 'Group', then 'Index', after that 'Ref', so this case will be sorted as (NFS, F1A), (NFS, F2L), (NFS-3M, F1A), (NFS-3M, F2L)

Comment: Have you tried to use `.sort_values`? It can handle more than one column as criterion.